# WebSocket Server https

Tags: javascript, php, https, websocket

I'm new with websocket things. I tried to make a simple chat application, and i've followed ratchet hello world tutorial. I ran it locally with

```
'ws://localhost:8080'
```

It's works perfectly fine. I can chat via javascript console like the tutorials said. Now, i try to put it on my webserver **https://some.domain.co/websocket**. I've tried to do the same thing like

```
'ws://some.domain.co:8080'
'ws://some.domain.co:8080/websocket'
'ws://some.domain.co/websocket:8080'
'wss://some.domain.co:8080'
'wss://some.domain.co:8080/websocket'
'wss://some.domain.co/websocket:8080'
```

But none of them work. By browser still give error

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://some.domain.co/' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

or

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://some.domain.co:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

I think i had something wrong with my url. Any advice? Thanks before

**Edit**

chatServer.php

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
include("Chat.php");

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ), 8080
);
$server->run();
```

Chat.php

```
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
   protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    echo "Server is Running\n";
}

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // Store the new connection to send messages to later
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}

public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
    echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
        , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        if ($from !== $client) {
            // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
            $client->send($msg);
        }
    }
}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

    $conn->close();
}
}
```

Comment: Questions about code pretty much always require that you include the relevant code IN the question.  Otherwise, you're just asking people to guess what you might have done wrong rather than show them the actual code and let them see what isn't right.

Comment: Edited with code @jfriend00

Comment: Have you deployed using the instructions here http://socketo.me/docs/deploy

Comment: sadly right now i don't have previleges to do that in my office. i'll talk to my friends about that. Any other alternative? or explaining why this case is happened?